# Create Product with image using REST API

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, rest-api, server-setup

I'm trying to create a product with an image using the REST API in Magento 2 but I get always 400 Error Code saying it's a bad request. Trying it without an image works but if I put the entry "media_gallery_entries" it doesn't work.

The encoded json looks like this:

```
{
"product": {
"sku": "KT909",
"name": "PrintaMent PURE 2.85 mm - Schwarz - 0,5 kg",
"price": 2.5,
"status": 1,
"type_id": "simple",
"attribute_set_id": 4,
"weight": 0.5,
"extension_attributes": {
  "website_ids": [
    1
  ],
  "category_links": [
    {
      "position": 2,
      "category_id": "3"
    }
  ],
  "stock_item": {
    "qty": 99
  }
},
"media_gallery_entries": [
  {
    "position": 2,
    "media_type": "image",
    "label": "test",
    "disabled": false,
    "content": {
      "base64_encoded_data": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD...",
      "type": "image/jpeg",
      "name": "3D-Drucker.jpg"
    }
  }
]
},
"saveOptions": true
}
```

Comment: just a couple of guessing: 1- why are you passing the id in the media_gallery_entries? it should not be needed and automatically generated. 2 - have you checked that the file is found by magento?  3- what about the base64 encoding? is it correct?  otherwise the request seems correct

Comment: I have removed the id tag and also the file tag, because it is not mandatory. But again, It's not working. I'm sending my request to https://www.../rest/V1/products with the POST method.

Comment: Now I have found out that it works, if I test it local (localhost). What could be the reason that it doesn't work on the server. I have checked the file permissions of the folder pub/media/images (777) but everything was ok.